Minimum or Stationary Value of a Mixed Boundary Problem
Take the volume integral of the dissipated DC current in a finite volume $\mathcal V$ of conductivity $\sigma$ and stationary potential distribution $\phi$ while assuming charge conservation $\nabla \cdot (\sigma \nabla \phi)=0$:
$$D_0[\phi]=\int_{\mathcal V} \sigma (\nabla \phi)^2dv \tag{1}\label{1}$$
When taking the first variation with respect $\phi$ we get
$$\delta D_0[\phi]=2\int_{\mathcal V}\sigma (\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \delta \phi) dv \tag{2},$$
which can be written as
$$\delta D_0[\phi]=2\int_{\mathcal V}[\nabla \cdot (\sigma \delta \phi \nabla \phi) - \delta \phi \nabla\cdot (\sigma \nabla \phi)] dv\\
=2\oint_{\partial \mathcal V}\sigma \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}\delta \phi  ds \tag{3}\label{3}.$$
Now let $\partial \mathcal V = \mathcal A' \cup \mathcal A''$ with $\mathcal A' \cap \mathcal A''=\varnothing$, then $\eqref{3}$ is implying that
$$\delta D_0[\phi]=0 
\begin{cases}\delta \phi(\mathcal A') = 0 \\\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}(\mathcal A'')=0\end{cases}.$$
In other words, we can prescribe the potential function on a portion of the $\mathcal A'$ of the boundary $\partial V$ arbitrarily and minimize the functional of $\eqref{1}$ at the same time leaving the behavior of $\phi$ on the rest of the boundary varying arbitrarily, and then the function minimizing $D_0[\phi]$ will be the one that has zero normal derivative on the rest of the boundary $\mathcal A''$, a so-called natural boundary condition.
Now if we are interested in a more complicated boundary condition on $\mathcal A''$ than just the normal derivative be zero, say $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} +f \phi=0$ along with $\delta \phi(\mathcal A')=0$ we can minimize the functional
$$D_1[\phi]=\int_{\mathcal V} \sigma (\nabla \phi)^2dv + \int_{\mathcal A''}f\phi^2 da\tag{4}\label{4}$$
As long as $f\ge 0$ the term $\int_{\mathcal A''}f\phi^2 da$ is also nonnegative and the $D_1 \ge 0$ so the stationary point is then minimum.
Now calculate the variation of $D_1$ with respect to $\phi$ and instead of $\eqref{3}$ to get :
$$\delta D_1[\phi]=2\oint_{\partial \mathcal V}\sigma \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}\delta \phi  ds +2 \int_{\mathcal A''}f\phi \delta \phi da \\
=2\oint_{\mathcal A'}\sigma \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}\delta \phi  ds +2 \int_{\mathcal A''}[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}+f\phi] \delta \phi da \tag{5}\label{5},$$
implying that $D_1$ is minimum if $\delta\phi(\mathcal A')=0$ and $[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}+f\phi](\mathcal A'')=0$ as required.
Now if we add to $D_0$ the term $g\phi(\mathcal A'')=0$ and calculate the first variation of
$$D_2[\phi]=\int_{\mathcal V} \sigma (\nabla \phi)^2dv + \int_{\mathcal A''}g\phi da\tag{6}\label{6}$$ the result is
$$\delta D_2[\phi]=2\oint_{\partial \mathcal V}\sigma \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}\delta \phi  ds + \int_{\mathcal A''}g \delta \phi da \\
=2\oint_{\mathcal A'}\sigma \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}\delta \phi  ds +2 \int_{\mathcal A''}[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}+\tfrac{1}{2}g] \delta \phi da, \tag{7}\label{7}$$ but in contrast to $\eqref{4}$ the term $\int_{\mathcal A''}g\phi da$ has no fixed sign irresepctive of what $g$ is, and although the natural boundary condition $[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}+\tfrac{1}{2}g](\mathcal A'')=0$ assures stationarity, it may not guarantee a minimum.
Question: is it possible to formulate this variational problem so that its stationary solution be a minimum while the natural boundary condition is that the normal derivative is an "arbitrary" prescribed function on a portion of the boundary $\mathcal A''$ and on the rest the potential function itself is prescribed.
